# Cannot invoke 'performSelector' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3, xcode8

I am working on xcode 8 beta and getting below error and not able to resolve.

**Cannot invoke '`performSelector`' with an argument list of type '(String)'**

```
func webView(WebViewNews: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

     if request.URL!.absoluteString.hasPrefix("ios:") {
        // Call the given selector
          self.performSelector("webToNativeCall")
       // Cancel the location change
          return false
       }
        return true
 }
```

Comment: Please post your full class.  What is the object that has the selector `webToNativeCall`?  Why not just call the function directly on `self`?  You shouldn't need `performSelector` for that

Answer (score 2):

`performSelector` has been renamed `perform(_ aSelector:)`:

```
class SomeClass: NSObject {

    func webToNativeCall() {
        // ...
    }

    func someFunc() {
        self.perform(#selector(webToNativeCall))
    }
}
```